# Dataverse CSV file line seperator

Tags: azure, pyspark, databricks, parquet, dataverse

having an issue with the reading the csv files and converting into paruqet files.

The CSV files are coming drom Dynamic 365 via dataverse and are stored into adls gen2 datalake.

This is how I read the csv files

```
df2 = (spark.read.format('csv')
       .option("delimiter", ",")
       .option("quote", '"')
       #.option("quoteAll", '"')
       .option("escape", '"')
       .option("header", "false")
       .option("path", '/mnt/d365/'+absolute+'/'+table_name+"/*.csv")
       .option("mode", "failfast")
       #.option("mode", "dropmalformed")
       #.option("mode", "permissive")
       .option("lineSep", "\r\n")
       .option("multiLine", "true")
       .schema(schema)
       .load()
  )
```

this is how im trying to convert them into paruqet files

```
for table in dataverse_dfs.keys():
try:
    (dataverse_dfs[table].write
     .mode('overwrite')
     .parquet(f'abfss://bronze@{storage_account_name_write}.dfs.core.windows.net/D365/{table}'))
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    raise Exception(e)
```

but I  get the error

> Caused by: com.univocity.parsers.common.TextParsingException: java.lang.IllegalStateException - Error reading from input
> Identified line separator characters in the parsed content. This may be the cause of the error. The line separator in your parser settings is set to '[crlf]'. Parsed content:

EDIT: I also tried "\n" which did not work too

Comment: What line endings does your file have?

Comment: when I open the file in notepad++ it says CR LF

Comment: @Jeronimo Backes can you please have look here?

Answer (score 0):

- The issue is with the line separator characters in the input data
  that you're trying to read using Spark.
- The error specifically mentions that the line separator in the parser
  settings is set to '[crlf]', which means it is expecting a line
  separator in the format of Carriage Return (CR) followed by Line Feed
  (LF).
- The error can occur due to a mismatch between the actual line
  separator characters in the data and the expected line separator
  specified in the parser settings.

I have tried the same approach at my end reading the CSV file from ADLS line separator characters

```
file_path = "abfss://gold@adlsgen2may15.dfs.core.windows.net/"
df = spark.read.format("csv").option("inferschema", "true").option("header", "true").option("delimiter", ",").option("lineSep", "\r\n").load(file_path)

display(df)
```

[image]

[image]
**writing to Parquet format**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
output_path = "abfss://gold@adlsgen2may15.dfs.core.windows.net/output/"
for column in df.columns:
    try:
        
        column_df = df.select(col(column))
        

        column_df.write.format("parquet").save(output_path + column, mode="overwrite")
        
        print("Successfully wrote column '{}' to Parquet format.".format(column))
    except:
        print("Error occurred while writing column '{}'.".format(column)
```

[image]

**Output written to ADLS**

[image]

[image]

Comment: could it be the reason that `csv` files that im trying to access they are consantly updated by `Dataverse`? Im guessing that if the files are updated evey second then of course spark cant define the line is finish since its in the process of the updating.  what could be solution in this case I can eliminate the last row in csv that is getting updating?

Comment: @Greencolor try without the line separator and see if your code is working.